# Is this pediococcus contamination?

Tags: fermentation, yeast, contamination, pediococcus

[image]

A berliner weisse we forgot to bottle for around a month and a half. Did not introduce pediococcus or lactic acid in the fermentation. Did a sour mash before the boil so lactobacillus shouldn't have been present.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely a wild yeast contamination which could easily contain some of those strains and have the potential to be a positive in a Berliner, or not...(plastic, bandaid, and phenolic flavors possible). It does Look like a pellicle for sure! I would say if it smells rancid don't try it, if it taste terrible don't drink it, that's the best advice given to me on the questionable safety of beer everything else and your good!